# Sql: regarding Update statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the SUIDMatches column of table1_orig_namesplits table based on number of matches it find in the master_table using the following update statement. 
But I am getting an "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'al.source_id' in 'on clause'" error.

```
UPDATE test.table1_orig_namesplits al
SET al.SUIDMatches = ( 
    SELECT count(distinct v.SUID)
    FROM test.master_table v 
    JOIN test.table1_orig a ON al.source_id = a.id_names
    WHERE al.name_first = v.FirstName 
    AND al.name_last = v.LastName 
    AND a.date_of_birth_dt = v.BirthDate_dt );
```

There is a `source_id` column in the `table1_orig_namesplits` table is matched with the `id_names` column of `table1_orig`. 
Can anyone please suggest how to fix this update statement?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the sub-query attempts to join `test.table1_orig` to `test.master_table` using a column from `test.table1_orig_namesplits` which is not part of the join.

For further testing / analysis some sample data would be helpful, but the basic idea is that you'll either have to join to `al` in the subquery, or take a different approach.